# Change color bounds for interaction variable in shap `dependence_plot`

Tags: python, matplotlib, shap

In the shap package for Python, you can create a partial dependence plot of SHAP values for a feature and color the points in the plot by the values of another feature. See example code below. Is there a way to set the bounds of the colors for the interaction variable set in the `interaction_index` parameter? The plot will apply coloring automatically based on the range of values in the variable `var_2`, but I would like to change the color scale bounds. For example, if the range of `var_2` goes from 0-20, I would like to tell the plot to have the color bounds be from 0-10. Is this possible?

```
import shap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
shap.dependence_plot(
    'var_1',
    shap_values,
    X_train,
    x_jitter=0.5,
    interaction_index='var_2',
    alpha=1,
    show=False
)
```

I have tried setting the `cmap` parameter in `shap.dependence_plot`, but this only changes the color mapping of `var_1` and does not allow for setting the bounds of the coloring. I'd like the color bounds of the `interaction_index` variable `var_2` to be changed.